# What is a fair ask for the first employee who built the majority of the product if you want to rehire him?

Tags: salary, negotiation, startup, equity

I need some advice because I'm not sure if I'm being unreasonable here.

TLDR: Joined friends startup (about 5-6 months in) on 6 month contract for salary and no equity. Built entire project from scratch. I am the only one working on it full-time and want to ask for co-ownership at 20%. Am I being unreasonable?

---

A long time friend and his best friend started a company 10 months ago.

They were both taking an entrepreneurship masters class and part of the program required they start a business. They got funding to hire someone to help them out with the idea. The funding was **20k (CAD) for 6 months** (About 20/hr normal shifts). I decided to **accept the position with no equity** for 6 months and we'd see how things would go from there. The pay was significantly below what I'd accept anywhere else (60k) but no risk no reward right.

By the time I joined, they were working on 1 side project for the school and I was suppose to work with the friend on the main project. Over the past 5 months, I built 95% of the entire thing. Worked on it 6-7 days a week and meet with them on Sundays to work on it at one of their houses. They both work full time somewhere else and I work full time on this.

So over this time, I focused on my project, his friend focused on the scheduling project one and my mate work the customer relationships and getting clients. Now my contract is coming to an end Dec 8th.

They've offered me another **contract of 6 months  at 25k with 5% equity.** They couldn't get money from the same fund as last time so this time it's coming from the money they made from selling to the school. It's basically all they have so I can't negotiate for more cash and I can live with the cash offered so I don't care about that.

They both currently have full-time jobs a year each so if this doesn't work out, they're covered. I feel pretty stupid putting my career on hold for a startup where I have only 5% ownership, am getting paid less than market rate to be the primary developer/designer/etc, and receive no benefits other than working from home.

I had dinner with the friend (the mutual one) last weekend. He felt we needed to talk because he could sense something was on my mind. He asked me where I saw myself in a few years and I said I want to me making decisions with them at the top. I'm not interested in just being another employee, if that's what I wanted I could do that anywhere else for a salary reflecting my skills and the work I put in. His response was "We're not really looking for another co-founder", I asked him what he was concerned with and for him, he just wants to be making all the decisions without having to justify himself.

Anyways, that's the situation. Just need to know what I should do. I'm going to work on my resume after this. My contract is done beginning of December so I should be prepared anyways. I've never really interacted with startups before and don't really know what my options are. I guess I'm just looking for feedback. I know that I want is a percentage of the company that reflects what I've put into it. My ideal number is **20%**. They both currently have %50 each and given the work and risks I've taken to be involved, I don't think I'm being unreasonable. I think an even split between the 3 of us isn't entirely fair since it was their idea, they did the leg work to get the company started and the initial funding, they've currently paid for the lawyer fees (or will at some point) and any other fees so I do get that.  But in my opinion I got in early enough and did enough of the leg work that 20% is a fair ask. I'd just love to here some opinions or options.

Thanks.

---

**More info**

1. Both of them received a 9k scholarship from the course where this all started so they put that 18k towards starting the business.
2. The project the other guy is working on, they sold that to the university for 30K.
3. They don't know how much they owe their lawyers yet. They're guessing that's going to be around 5-10k
4. We're not at seeding stage, the product hasn't launched yet, I don't think they've talked to any investors yet so there's no guarantee of any future revenue at this time.

---

Update: They weren't willing to negotiate and I thought the offer was too low. So even if I had accepted, it would have just fostered resentment. So looks like I just need to find something else to do now.

Comment: "No risk, no reward" It's unclear what. The 'reward' is. You've essentially donated your time up to now (the entire product) and nothing compels your 'friends' to cut you in in exchange. You need to understand how badly you've been played before you can proceed.

Comment: Yea I got it. I'm getting screwed. Tomorrow I will let him know what I want and explain why. Either they accept or I start looking for something else.

Comment: This is such a specific situation that I feel it meets and exceeds the criteria for closing as an advice question. Asking "Just need to know what I should do." doesn't help. I think you've got some useful input below but I don't think there are any real "answers" to be found here. If you have a specific question like "how do I make the argument for more equity" then that may be a valid question. Consider asking for advice in the Workplace or Startups SE chatrooms.

Comment: Maybe you should move the TLDR summary to the top?

Comment: So far they have another done 2 projects. Is another even lined up? You know how start ups are, they usually flash then peter out pretty quick. And if the two 'founders' aren't dedicated enough to only work on it part time, its easier to define this as a hobby.

I wouldn't sweat much right now, see if anything else happens. Why get in a big argument and build resentment with your friends about owning 33% of a company that is just a couple dudes hanging out after work.

Comment: @Brandin I  made the change.

Comment: @DanShaffer it's a couple dudess hangout out after work but for me it's a decision about my career path. Am I going to keep getting underpaid for the potential that 5% in the future will be worth something or should I leave now and go find a job or start my own venture. They don't have another project lined up, the project  I'm working on hasn't been launched and is really the main focus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about navigating the workplace but about determining a proper equity.  Remuneration amounts are specifically declared off topic here.

Comment: That's fine, I was hesitant on posting here but I got some really good answers either way.

Comment: The point I was trying to make, if I understand everything, is they have a backup plan, they have regular jobs. In December, you won't. You shouldn't let this side project of theirs interfere with your livelihood or your chance to find a full time job.

Comment: @DanShaffer you're 100% right. If they don't want to give me what I'm asking for I'll let them know I'm out but willing to work part-time at a rate I find acceptable with no equity.

Comment: I believe your leverage in this situation comes from *not* offering to work part-time.

Comment: I completely disagree about closing the question.  It's garnered a lot of interest and the fact that a "correct" answer will be lost in the nuances of it are not a disadvantage!  I vote to re-open.  (if I could vote.)

Comment: "They've offered me another contract of 6 months at 25k with 5% equity." and "pay was significantly below what I'd accept anywhere else (60k)" suggests they are valuing the company at $100k right now.  If you do not agree with that evaluation then state you feel is worth X, your salary elsewhere would be $30k so the $5k shortfall needs to be made up with X% stock.  Your risk is the stock is worth $0 in 6 months.

Comment: Please come back in 6 or 12 months and tell us how it worked out for them

Answer (score 22):

The answer is pretty simple:  You are, for all intents and purposes, the "primary angel investor" in this venture.

Communicate to them that by taking a significantly-below-market rate, you're essentially investing in the company.  For the last six months, you've "invested" the equivalent of CAN$40k, which is the difference between your rate and the typical market rate you can command, meanwhile carrying all of the risk and none of the reward.  At the end of December, it can be credibly argued that on paper at least, you've "invested" a large share, if not perhaps the largest share.  So, what is that worth?

If over the course of the last six months, you've "invested" $40k in the form of uncompensated value, and through to the end of the company's first fiscal year you expect to "invest" another $35k...then you've "invested" $75k in the venture.  At the end of the fiscal year, what do they expect their venture's reasonable valuation to be?  When they DO walk into that seed "A" round with investors, what's their valuation?

For the sake of putting numbers on it, if the valuation of the company is expected to be $1million, then your contribution is about a 7.5% stake.  To properly and appropriately apply a risk premium to your investment, you're reasonable to expect this to bump to about 10%.

Comment: I like the line of thinking that I'm an Angel investor :) 
If there's no way they see it that way but if I'm foregoing money to build something for you then it does make sense to think about it that way.

Comment: good positioning, Batman.  they're offering you 5% and at the strawman valuation I imagined, they're not terribly far off.  Bear in mind that every penny that they grant you comes out of their own pockets.  That's different than when this scenario happens after the "A" round and the money is coming out of someone else's pocket.

Comment: also...by the paperwork, you HAVE NOT invested in this company.  This is all still "handshake" territory.  It's easy for that to become soiled and spoiled...so tread lightly, carefully.

Comment: I'm not sure on which side of things you're on now with these last two comments. Are you saying what I'm asking for is unreasonable or just informing me of the reality of the situation. You're right that on paper I'm nothing, just a cog in their machine but given that my time is almost up, I have no choice but to negotiate for myself now and make sure I can get the best deal possible because I'm clearly the only person looking out for me here.

Comment: Additionally, I  liked your calculation to 10% but that's on the an assumed value of 1million. How do I do that when there's no proper valuation because the smaller the number the higher my share should be right.

Comment: exactly:  If their valuation is higher, by this rubric your contribution is a smaller percentage, and vice versa.  Which side am I on?  Neither side.  How could I be on anyone's side?  :)  just pointing out realities.  They don't technically owe you anything, and it's a good sign that they're willing to acknowledge that you deserve an equity position.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't asking in terms of "are on my side or theirs" more in the sense of "am I being on reasonable or is their offer poor". You're right in saying they don't owe me anything. If I didn't like the original offer I shouldn't have accepted it, it's weakened my negotiating power.  Anyways, considering what they've put in which is give or take 50-60k (layer, school grant, revenue from sale) and say market rate for a lead dev is 70-80k and i'm getting 45k so foregoing 25-35k, say 30/90 = 33% share +/- risk factor ....I'm asking for 20%, seems reasonable to me.

Comment: No, he's not an "Angel" investor.  He was paid a rate for his work.  The amount of work put in isn't germane.  What matters is that he decided to perform the work for the amount given.  I don't see anywhere in this where the owners led him to believe that he was accruing any type of ownership or other compensation.  Also there is no such thing as "uncompensated value".  If he agrees to a price (regardless of the lost opportunity cost) then that's the value.

Comment: @Batman: One thing you seem to be missing is that the original funding they received has already cost them some amount of ownership.  Without knowing the terms of that deal, they might have already given up 20 or even 50% of the business.  Giving you another 20% might very well put them in the position of no longer having majority ownership which would be a nightmare for them and could easily tank the business before it gets off the ground.

Comment: @NotMe hey thanks for the reply. The original funding was a grant. They did not have to give any equity for it. It's just a city program to help connect start ups with new engineers who are having a hard time to find a job. They knew I had experience so they just sweet talked the organization into using the money on me. So as it stands, they both currently still own %50 each.

Comment: @NotMe...you seem to miss the adamant flag-waving that  Batman's work was "like" investing...as in, not REALLY investing, but SIMILAR to, or AKIN to, or "LIKE."

Comment: "No, he's not an 'Angel' investor." That argument is fine too. If they're unwilling to take into account the amount of successful work he did, then he should consider his replacement cost and his own opportunity cost. Contrary to popular belief, software engineers are not easily interchangeable. If they hire someone to replace him at this stage, it's going to be a huge gamble for them. He should keep this in mind while negotiating, and at the same time, he should look for work elsewhere to see what his real value is on the open market. Right now, he's not being objective about his true worth.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, we agree completely that he is not an actual angel investor...he's been contributing/investing the value of his opportunity cost, and that's worth almost just enough to buy a cup of coffee at this point.  I present the "angel" notion as a way to rationalize the valuation of his services to the venture.  I echo your point about his "stickyness" as a developer...it would take several months on a non-trivial project for someone new to become productive...time that they may not have to spend.  I'd counsel caution about using it as "ransom" though!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: Regardless of how the work turned out, he completed it for a predetermined price.  Looking back on it and trying to say he should now get a part of the extra value the company received from that work is a non-starter.  So I disagree that any lost opportunity by the OP should be categorized as an "investment", regardless of supposed "value".  That said, I agree that the OP should try to find another job if for no other reason than to actually know what his skills are worth.

Comment: @NotMe, "Looking back on it and trying to say he should now get a part of the extra value the company received from that work is a non-starter." I disagree. This is a negotiation. He can start from any place he wants to. The fact is, he did the work for below market value. He wasn't acting perfectly rationally at the time. He doesn't need to start acting rationally now either.  If anything, he needs to start shedding his nice guy attitude right now. The "angel" notion is a good one to present to those guys. He should use it.

Comment: (continued...) After all, what are they going to say? You screwed up accepting the contract we initially made with you. That's your fault, not ours. Of course, they're not going to say that.

Comment: @NotMe, I also disagree.  The very definition of an underfunded startup is "put in sweat equity in lieu of real pay, with the hope/expectation of a back-end payday in the form of REAL equity."  That's the norm.  Working as a software engineer on new technology, for landscaper's wages, and "that's the deal," is not the norm.  I again reiterate, because you seem to keep missing it, that nobody's suggesting that he's accrued ACTUAL equity at this point, only goodwill.  Hopefully, he can parlay that goodwill into actual equity, which is really the BEST form of goodwill!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: If you and I agree on the price for something and I deliver and you pay me then I have zero standing to decide that price should have been higher *after the fact*.  Yes, he should absolutely negotiate on this new contract - that isn't my issue.  My issue is that this answer makes it sound like he is supposed to treat his past performance (that he was paid for, at a rate he agreed to) as some sort of investment.  It wasn't.

Comment: (continued) He also doesn't need to drop the "nice guy attitude".  It's simple, either they can agree on the compensation for further work or they don't; no need to go in guns blazing or trying to strong arm them into doing what he wants.

Comment: First, it was @dwoz that called it a "ransom". Now, it's NotMe that calls it "strong arming" or "guns blazing". "Ransom" implies to me that a theft occurred and now that he's ransoming it back to them, or that somehow now that he has an unfair advantage because of all the work he put in.  That's ridiculous. And "strong arming", I suppose one could call anything "strong arming" if that means making the implied threat to walk away. By that definition, the two original founders are also "strong arming" the developer too, since obviously, if they don't get their way, they'll refuse to hire him.

Comment: @NotMe, This guy isn't an inanimate object. Objects don't make sacrifices. Objects don't learn. If I work for you as a developer for less than minimum wage, don't be surprised when I ask for way more money than market rate if the project happens to be successful, assuming you want me to continue working on it. After all, I think it's been conceded that even if you pay someone else market rate by that point, that this new person will need at least three months to get up to my speed (assuming they can even get up to my speed which is a huge terrible gamble in itself).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, just to be clear, I think we're in alignment here, you and I.

Answer (score 11):

There are two aspects here

1. Co founding
2. Total remuneration

It sounds like being up as a co founder/director is out of the question, so you need to decide if that's a deal breaker for you.

Then as an entirely separate question, you need to look at the salary package as an employee. I would expect either a near-market rate salary plus small equity, or a larger equity stake with a smaller salary.

Essentially any equity you take is a risky investment in the company, so it needs to be high enough to justify that risk.

How much do you expect the company to be worth in a couple of years time, if all goes to plan? What share of equity would you therefore need in order that if you sold your equity at that stage, you'd make at least as much as if you'd simply worked at market rate for the same amount of time? Now how much more do you want to account for the risk of failure?

If taking less than market rate, you're essentially investing the difference in the company, so treat it like that.

Comment: somehow missed this answer when I posted...gives much the same answer as I did.  Kudos, Jon.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  The way I see it, chances that the company makes anywhere near enough for a 5% stack is not  enough for me to feel comfortable foregoing market rate of a full stack developer, especially one involved so early in the stage of the company (I joins 5-6 months in). So their offer as it stands does not work for me on the employee aspect of things. On the co-founder side of things, if they aren't willing to include me as one, there's nothing I can say to convince them to do so. Either they want me or they don't. All I can do is counter their offer or walk.

Comment: Exactly: decide on both parts individually and walk if either of them are a no.

Comment: Anyone else in this situation, don't just calculate base don salary; include all benefits when calculating (pensions, paid time off, sickness, medical plans, etc, etc)

Comment: @Mawg That comes under "Total remuneration" and "salary package" in the answer - when we talk about a salary package, we generally mean salary + bonuses + benefits, not just base salary

Answer (score 9):

"Fairness" doesn't exactly equate into this scenario.  Even if you've built much of this project, and you personally enjoy working with the founders, you feel that you are worth more than what they are currently offering, and as such, you should make that clear to them.

They may consider the offer you're making to be unreasonable since it's been steady pay, but this isn't just about them now - it's also about you.  You should be ready to and defend your compensation asks, as well as move on if the company decides not to accept it.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much the consensus. Tell them what I want, stick to my guns. Either they accept or they don't and if they don't I walk.

Answer (score 6):

5% is ridiculous, I'd ask for equal shares and negotiate down to 20% at most and take the loss in earnings, anything less and you're being used. You're the one taking the risk, you're the one doing the work. If you're going to do it for peanuts you might as well develop for yourself and take the whole pie.

I have been in this sort of situation, basically you're working at a loss to make someone else rich, you're not doing yourself any favours by doing so. Do a simple equation, how much do they need you versus how much you need them. In my experience from similar situations they need you more, so make sure you're on the winning side of it. If they don't think so, then don't take less, decide how saleable the product is and do another equation.

Is it worth doing it yourself versus the risks in doing so. It's possible that you could redevelop the idea from scratch and be selling it before they can even get off the ground. I'm always wary of people who look around for funding to do everything without the expertise to actually do it themselves when they have the funding. Sometimes people like that make a career of looking for funding and then just getting enough done for the next round of looking for funding leaving a line of developers behind them who didn't make anything worthwhile out of it.

Comment: I'm downvoting because there is FAR more involved in getting a company off the ground than just having a developer write some code.  The founders had an idea, they got some minor funding (no small feat), they made a sale, etc.  These are HUGE items that outstrip code writing and, quite frankly, take far more time than the OP is letting on.  Also, who knows how much they've already had to give up just to get the funding that paid the OP to begin with.  Early investments cost quite a bit.

Comment: @NotMe Thanks for the explanation (Y) Appreciate it, but having started more than one business and been on the developer angle as well more than once I'll stick by my answer. At the end of the day I can only give input from my personal experience, which may not always be normal I guess.

Comment: I guess we have different definitions of risk.  The OPs risk is that they end up out of a job at some point.  The founders risk is that they (depending on company structure) end up financially liable for failures.  A further risk is that their *currently unpaid for efforts* continue to be unpaid; and the final risk is that their financial investment is lost ($30k at this point).  From the numbers given, the only one who has made any money on this deal is the OP as the costs shown easily outweigh the amount taken in.

Comment: @NotMe Yes, we define it differently, to me the OP has been making a loss (could have been employed elsewhere for more) and stands to make the biggest loss of being out of a job as well as out of pocket. The 30K wasn't their money and couldn't have been spent on something else, so it's not being risked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to establish your ownership now and either the risk/reward potential is acceptable or you should move on to other jobs or ventures. At this point in the venture there should not be another "contract" or "let's see how the next six months goes."

Negotiating at this point should focus on their reluctance to give you more equity vs. their reluctance to quit their jobs and/or find a replacement for you. So far, there is no actual value in the company to negotiate. The "idea" guys must relinquish equity as people, like you, provide unique contributions to the success of the company besides the idea itself.

With that in mind, do not sacrifice equity out of eagerness to create a deal. The company should consider the cost if you do not renew the contract. This is important because the other owners are employed, which violates the risk-reward formula. You can't compare their "partial dedication" to your full dedication. Any worthwhile idea has lots of competition, so the idea is not as valuable as the people's skill, commitment and devotion to the success of the idea. Those things create value more than anything else at this point in a company's evolution.

You should expect their full time commitment as soon as possible for the success of the company, with the expectation that the longer their delay in joining your full-time commitment, the more equity you should expect now. Otherwise you might find yourself with a long series of below-market contracts for small pieces of a company that does not have enough support to succeed.

Similarly, it is important to not overvalue your contribution. The company may be able to transition to another similarly skilled developer willing to accept the terms offered you. The business might benefit from another developer's perspective. This is more difficult the more you can offer unique perspective or have done work outside of software development to help the business succeed. A more difficult transition to another developer is not unfair leverage of your development work, it is an indication of your unique value to the company. If you walk away and things continue without you, you were probably offered too much equity. And this may not be a loss to you - again, without more support, the company will almost certainly falter and your resume will not suffer.

Consider if you "shop around" for start-up "CTO" or "CIO" positions, they are primarily in the 1-25% equity range (rarely higher or lower). It seems that you have reasonable expectations, including your current and desired amounts. This is a fair range, and the conditions above are the means of measuring it.

A lower equity position encourages stability but is an indication that your role is more a commodity to the business than a strategic advantage. While a larger share is an indication of unique contribution for a critical component of the business (including your willingness to devote full time to the success of the company when others are unwilling).

Last, this negotiation will probably be the largest offer you will get (whether it is the 5% or the 20% you seek). If the company is successful, then additional ownership options will be smaller (as a percentage). If the company fails you will not get additional offers of equity unless you acquire a failing company.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot of taking the time to write this. I just wanted to clarify, when you say "This is probably the largest offer you will get", are you saying they are likely not going to give me the percentage I want, even though you think it's reasonable?

Comment: No - I edited the response (I hope it is more clear). Whatever you negotiate during this contract is likely to be the largest you will get based on your description of the company's status.

Comment: Oh I see, basically it's now or never, so don't agree to bs terms.

Comment: Something like that, yes. Percentages of this size are rarely discussed unless it involves substantial investment or bankruptcy.

Comment: Yea I agree. It really should have been something I discussed before I agreed to do anything. That put me at a disadvantage. I'm meeting him in a few hours. The math, and pretty much all the feedback agrees with me. If they don't, at least I'll know I made an informed decision.